# the component not loaded in ngafterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, intervals

I need to implement scrool with an anchor (in my case skip the link).

```
<div class="skip-link" >
    <a accesskey="1" tabindex="0" id="skiplink1" [routerLink]="url" [fragment]="SKIP_LINK_URL"> {{ 'APPLICATION.HEADER.a' | translate }}</a>
</div>


<app-header>

</app-header>
<router-outlet [id]="SKIP_LINK_URL" style="position: relative"></router-outlet>
```

TO PASS THE URL IN MY TS I DO:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {   

    this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
      if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {

          let locationUrl: string = ev.url;   
    
       
           const firstHash= locationUrl.indexOf('#'+this.SKIP_LINK_URL);
           if (firstHash!== -1) {
               locationUrl = locationUrl.substring(0, firstHash);
             
                this.scrollBottom();          //here is the problem because I think the component is not created
             
           }
        this.url = locationUrl;     
     
    
      }
    }


scrollBottom() { 
    this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(this.SKIP_LINK_URL);
   
  }
```

The problem is `this.scrollBottom();` because when this method is executed the component is not created.  I know that the method `ngAfterViewInit` is called after the view is created so I don't why there is this problem. I try to put a `set interval` in  `this.scrollBottom();` and the programs works fine, but I don't want use an interval solution.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: The method is deep into the function and wrapped by two conditional statements. They should both evaulate to true for it to be executed. Be sure that this is the case. Also check that AfterViewInit interface is being implemented in this component. i.e, implments OnInit, AfterViewInit{}

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to a specific spot on a given page via angular, basically?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it using ngAfterViewChecked() instead of ngAfterViewInit()